# Is it a (minor) typo in the proof of Roman Vershynin's "High dimensional probability with application to data science" (linked), Theorem 3.1.1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-matrices

So I've been currently studying [this book](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html#) on high dimensional probability by Roman Vershynin, which I find pretty awesome! However, I was wondering if in the first line of the proof of Theorem 3.1.1 (P. 43), where he proved a concentration inequality for high dimensional random vectors with independent components, it should be "*it follows that*" instead of "*for simplicity, we can assume that*"? This is because, since he assumed that $EX_i^2=1 \forall i,$:

$$2 \ge E[e^\frac{{X_i^2}}{||X_i||_{\psi_2}^2}] \ge E[1 + \frac{{X_i^2}}{||X_i||_{\psi_2}^2}] = 1 + \frac{{EX_i^2}}{||X_i||_{\psi_2}^2} = 1 + \frac{1}{||X_i||_{\psi_2}^2},$$ implying ${||X_i||_{\psi_2}^2} \ge 1 \forall i$.

Just checking to make sure, thanks!

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: @user58955 Thanks for checking!

Comment: You can get proper norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`. You can get properly sized brackets (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @joriki will do that from now on - thanks for pointing out!